# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW

Tags: java

I run my Java program and have following error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Attempt to allocate stack guard pages failed.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Attempt to unguard stack red zone failed.
[error occurred during error reporting (null), id 0xc0000005]#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW (0xc00000fd) at pc=0x000000006b7b18a7, pid=4408, tid=4788#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
 [jvm.dll+0x2118a7]#
Failed to write core dump.
```

The question is how to configure Java to write core dump correctly? And how to diagnose what was wrong in my code?

Comment: It seems that you are running the JVM in some unusual way. You should describe this in some detail.

Answer (score 0):

This error denotes that JVM (`jvm.dll`) has caught a operative system signal, related with an error, in this case a `EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW`.

Oracle has a very extensive document about [Troubleshooting guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/toc.html) where it covers some issues as yours. See [crash due to stack overflow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/crashes001.html#CIHDGFJA).

This documents describes how to use JVM tools to debug a problem, and also it tells you how to [enable core dumps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/bugreports004.html#CHDJJAJE) but keep in mind, core dumps are intended for reporting bugs to Oracle, you won't find useful info for you.

I developed some JNI packages and I debugged some issues on my C code, but your problem is with `jvm.dll` so this is different and have no experience.